# How to automate bulk upload on Hootsuite with images?

Tags: facebook, images, instagram, hootsuite

I want to do bulk posts with the csv uploader on Hoot Suite.  However, there is no clear way to automate the image uploading for Instagram and Facebook.  All of the examples I have found require the user to manually click and edit each post by selecting the photo from my local computer.

**Is there a way to format the fields in the csv uploader to pull directly from a url?** For example, if I post to imgur, could I use those image url paths in any of the fields?

https://help.hootsuite.com/hc/en-us/articles/222630868-Bulk-Composer

Comment: I just got down voted and Im new to the community.  Can you give me any insight on why this was downvoted so I can make future posts better?

Comment: Hi O.rka, I can't speak for the downvoter, so I don't know what their reasoning was.  This looks fine to me.